# Integral $\int \dfrac{2\sqrt[5]{2x-3}-1}{(2x-3)\sqrt[5]{2x-3}+\sqrt[5]{2x-3}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$I=\int \frac{2\sqrt[5]{2x-3}-1}{(2x-3)\sqrt[5]{2x-3}+\sqrt[5]{2x-3}}\,dx$$

it somehow makes sense to me that i should use substitution $2x-3=t^5 \Rightarrow dx=\frac{5}{2}t^4\,dt$

so now i have integral

$$I=\int \frac{2t-1}{t^6+t}\frac{5}{2}t^4\,dt$$

which is equal to

$$I=\frac{5}{2} \int \frac{t^3(2t-1)}{t^5+1}\,dt \Rightarrow I = \frac{5}{2} \int \frac{2t^4-t^3}{t^5+1}\,dt = \int \frac{5t^4}{t^5+1}\,dt - \int \frac{t^3}{t^5+1}\,dt$$

Now, if i made any mistakes up here i would like someone to point that out, in case everything is correct, i would like to know what to do with the rest of it, i mean, first integral is easy to solve, since then numerator is the derivative of denominator solution is natural logarithm of denominator, but the second part is confusing, how can i solve that integral, i mean i know that $x^5+1$ has one real and two pairs of complex solutions, but how can i find them and would that be the correct solution to this integral?

Comment: Factor the rightmost term into linear+2 quadratics. Then Partial fractions,  should allow you to rewrite it into a form you can integrate.

Comment: this stupid integral is showing up the third time in the last 1 or 2 weeks

Comment: @tired sorry, but  i haven't saw any of the previous posts with this integral, can you send me the link of it if someone already answered my questions in one of the previous two posts, because i can't find it

Comment: @tired vote to close as a duplicate instead of leaving a non-constructive comment

Comment: If you see on wolframalpha the answer is horrible so i think you need to try differently